# How to handle Handle the dynamic element ids in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium, I have started learning Selenium Web driver, on part of that, i have taken 'Yahoo.com' as application to log in automatically using web driver.I have strange problem, every time the id of the 'username' and 'password' is being changed.

I have tried following code:

```
WebElement user = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("passwd"));
```

Everytime these ids are being changed :(

Please help me how to handle this scenario.

Thanks in advance,

Raj

Comment: Try to use XPath instead of id.

Comment: The site you are referring here is wrong. Paste `html`

Answer (score 0):

Checked with site [yahoo.com site](https://login.yahoo.com/). I have modified my code since the name/ids were different for chrome and firefox. The below code works fine with Chrome and Firefox.

Try the below code:

```
WebElement user = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Yahoo ID' or @placeholder='Yahoo username']"));
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password']"));
```

Comment: Your answer is incorrect! The `username` field has `name="login"` but you are correct about the `password` field.

Comment: You must have seen inspected in Chrome. I did in firefox. And the name is **"username"** for the username field.. :)

Comment: I am referring to the site you provided. And, tested these on `ie,ff,chrome`. Plus, I don't think attribute value changes depending on the browsers.

Comment: I know. But that's the crazy part. I can provide you with screenshots if you want. Trust me, both have different ids, if username field is concerned..

Comment: Don't get me wrong dude! I got confused with OP's question as well. I guess that's what OP's is trying to say

Comment: Hey, no problem. It was your doubt that led me scouring the FF and Chrome for the relevant ids.  Thanks to you, now I know that there was something fishy about ids.. :)