# how i can handle dynamic "Id" in Selenium web driver?

Tags: eclipse, selenium

How i can handle Dynamic "id" in Selenium Web driver, In my web form there is multiple session(e.g session start date and session end date) when i create a new session id of session is change how i can handle dynamic id in selenium webdriver?

Html code

```
<td id="_start_time_td_3" class="ui-widget-content">
    <input type="text" id="_start_time_3"
        name="start_time[]" maxlength="100" style="width: 120px;
        text-align: left;" class="starttime" required="required">
</td>
```

Selenium code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("_start_time_1")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[10]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("_end_time_1")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[11]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div")).click();
```

Comment: Can you share that web page URL? or html  code? I think you should use Xpath.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088085/how-to-handle-handle-the-dynamic-element-ids-in-selenium-webdriver?rq=1

Comment: no its not duplicate

Comment: @miparnisari because when we create a new row id ,css can be Change

Answer (score 1):

you can select the element by classname instead of id

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='starttime']"));
```

or using contains

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'start_time')]"));
```